# Type error of function 'floor' in Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point, int

I have a function accepting 2 Ints n, x, and calculates floor (log n/log x). Here n and x are both very limited so Int is enough for me.

`func :: Int -> Int -> Int 

func n x = floor (log . fromIntegral n / (log . fromIntegral x))`

but here comes the error in ghci:

```
No instance for (RealFrac (a -> b))
  arising from a use of `floor' at p5_evenly_divide.hs:20:11-63
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac (a -> b))
In the expression:
    floor (log . fromIntegral n / (log . fromIntegral x))
In the definition of `func':
    func n x = floor (log . fromIntegral n / (log . fromIntegral x))
```

How can I get through this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression `log . fromIntegral n` is equivalent to `log . (fromIntegral n)`, not `(log . fromIntegral) n`, which is probably what you wanted. Just `log (fromIntegral n)` is probably more readable, though.

For general edification, when the error message says `No instance for (RealFrac (a -> b))` it's telling you it can't figure out how to use a function as a fractional number, which it's trying to do because you're applying function composition `(.)` to the result of `fromIntegral n`. It is a little obtuse in this case.

Comment: I like how you explained both the problem and how to troubleshoot it. That's really helpful.

Comment: I thought that error message is saying 'floor' should be used on a RealFrac, so I kept tackling on the wrong direction.

Comment: @Ralph Zhang: That's pretty much also true--`floor` and `(/)` need a fractional number type, `fromIntegral` can produce any number type, the only thing that forces a specific type is `(.)`. Everything would type check if functions *did* have a `RealFrac` instance, so that's what it complains about.

Comment: @camccann: +1 for the nice explanation, +1 for the info comment, learned something new about (.).

Comment: `log $ fromIntegral n` is very readable too, and quite idiomatic, afaict.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
func :: Int -> Int -> Int 
func n x = floor (k n / k x) where
  k = log . fromIntegral
```